# Can't reverse match url in Admin Changeform

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I read lot's of docs, tried everything and still can't understand why my template returns Reverse for '' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found error. Please see error dump here: http://dpaste.com/721187/

The tag I use in change_form.html template is {% url pdfview 1 %}

The class FVatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) has get_urls method which looks like this:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(FVatAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
       url(r'^view/(?P<id>\d+)', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.pdf_view), name="pdfview"),
       url(r'^js/calculate', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.calculate), name="calc"),
        )
    return my_urls + urls
```

The url and pdfview defined above work just fine, but somewhat don't resolve via {% url pdfview 1 %} in a template and via reverse('pdfview', args={1}) in a view or via shell.

I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm a newbie in Django... H E L P :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put url name in quotes.

```
{% url "admin:pdfview" 1 %}
```

UPDATE: this applies only for Django 1.3/1.4 if:

```
 {% load url from future %}
```

is used.

Comment: He's asking about reversing admin URLs - this response doesn't help with that.

Comment: yeah, it should be admin:pdfview

Comment: well, admin:pdfview doesn't work too, please see my comment to vkryachko answer for details.

Comment: can you post whole ``change_form.html`` template.

Comment: by traceback, it looks you are indeed using url tags from future, you should quote view name: {% url "admin:pdfview" 1 %}. I updated answer

Comment: yep, now in quotes it works! yay! thanks so much, but why quotes? Previously I read that quotes shouldn't be used with {% url %} tag...

Comment: glad it works :) check release notes for historical accident [url templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi).

Answer (score 1):

Django admin urls are namespaced in order not to clash with other urls.

Try doing the following {% url admin:pdfview 1 %}

See this for details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces

Comment: I tried this too and I receive a **Could not parse the remainder: ':pdfview' from 'admin:pdfview'** error, tracback is here http://dpaste.com/721417/ Something is wrong here. Maybe I should post some other parts of my script here to figure where's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my answer, fixed it now.  {% **url** admin:pdfview 1 %} is the right way to do it.